# How to custom OrderBy in Laravel

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I wanted to do a custom ordering for `marketing_status_id` in this:

```
$prospect = $this->filterProspect($request->all())
            ->select([
                'student_marketings.*',
                'students.name',
                'students.identification_type_id',
            ])
            ->distinct('student_marketings.id')
            ->orderBy('student_marketings.marketing_status_id');
```

How to order it in this sequence: `('marketing_status_id', 5, 20, 4, 1, 3, 18, 6)` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use mysql inbuilt-method `field()` like this:

```php
$prospect = $this->filterProspect($request->all())
            ->select([
                'student_marketings.*',
                'students.name',
                'students.identification_type_id',
            ])
            ->distinct('student_marketings.id')
            ->orderBy(DB::raw('FIELD(marketing_status_id, 5, 20, 4, 1, 3, 18, 6)'));
```

Comment: or `->orderByRaw('FIELD(marketing_status_id, 5, 20, 4, 1, 3, 18, 6)')`